# Debugging RPM scriptlets with -x

Tags: rpm

Is there a way to get `/bin/sh -x` style output from RPM while it's running a scriptlet? I would like to debug RPM installations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put `set -x` at the beginning of any scriptlet. And `rpm -ivvh` to install it will give you more than you would want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting an exit 1 in %post scriptlet, then run sh -x on the temporary file left when the upgrade fails (after removing the exit from the temp file).